# Events vs listenTo in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm new to Backbone and am confused by the difference between the events hash (events {}) and listenTo that you put in the initialize method. Why would you use one over the other. Isn't the events hash set up on initialize?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`events` is used for attaching event listeners on DOM elements. Backbone uses [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) technique for binding the handlers behind the scenes.

`listenTo` is used for listening to Backbone related events, and you don't have to use it in the `initialize` function's context. For example you can use the `listenTo` method of a View object for listening to `change` event of a Backbone collection.